# iOS - error 'No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'contents ofDirectoryAtPath...'

Tags: ios

I have the following code in my app but I get an error message which I do not understand:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSBundle * aBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSArray *filmgr;
NSError* error = nil;
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [filmgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSDocumentDirectory error:&error]);
```

the error I get is:

> 'No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'contents ofDirectoryAtPath...'

What does it mean?

How do I fix it please?

I must admit, I am totally new to iOS and the above code is a hodge podge of codes I found on this very site, copied and pasted without fully understanding them. I am trying them see what they do and learn how things work in ios. So any help showing the correct way of coding is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error` is a `NSFileManager` method, no a `NSArray` (`filmgr`) one.

Comment: …and filmgr = nil… when you use it in your log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you're trying to call the method `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:` on an object of type `NSArray`.

This method does not exist on objects of this type. Try calling it on an `NSFileManager` instance.

And even worse, you're trying to call `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:` on a non initialized object (`NSArray *filmgr;` does not fully create the array).